# redactor.js Word markup

Tags: ms-word, redactor

I implemented redactor.js as a wysiwyg Editor (comes installed with Statamic CMS). I also activated the cleanup feature. But when I check all the Word Code is kept when pasting things from word resulting in big pile of code waste. Tought we aren't in the 90ies anymore.

Has anybody had this problem too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback function with `pasteBeforeCallback` :

```
function cleanWordPaste( in_word_text ) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = in_word_text;
    var newString = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;

    newString  = newString.replace(/\n\n/g, "<br />").replace(/.*<!--.*-->/g,"");

    for ( i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
        if ( newString.substr(0,6)=="<br />" ) { 
        newString = newString.replace("<br />", ""); 
    }

    return newString;
}

$('#redactor').redactor({
    pasteBeforeCallback: function(html)
    {
        return cleanWordPaste(html);
    }
});
```